# UITableView reloadData

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

I have a UIViewController that contains a UITableView.

I'm trying to fill this table with data parsed from an XML file.

The first time the TableView loads the data isn't available just yet.

What would be the best way to reload this view?

I tried to do a self.TableView reloadData after the parsing finished.

Unfortunately the NSMutableArray holding the parse result getting reset during reloadData.

The array is set at the UIVivewController.

Should I set the NSMutablearray as a global variable?

THanks a bunch

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The array should be an ivar (instance variable) of the view controller containing the `UITableView`. When you are done parsing the ivar should be populated with the data and you should be able to populate the `UITableView` with no problem using `[self.TableView reloadData]`. Make sure you are not removing all objects or re-initializing the array in any of the delegate or datasource callbacks.

Comment: I think my problem is that I call the parsing twice as it's fired when the view loads. You are correct I re-initializing the array. I was initially going after global variable but I think it would be only a quick patch. At the end I don't want to parse twice. I need either set up a flag to prevent the second parse or use NSNotificationCenter.

Answer (score 2):

Don't make it global, make it an instance variable.  As in:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
    NSMutableArray* parsedDataArray;  //declare the array here
}
@end
```

But beyond that, yes, calling `reloadData` after the parsing finishes is reasonable.  Just fix the code to not reset the parse results when `reloadData` is called.

Comment: Do you mean I should create some kind of a flag that prevents the parsing run more than once? Rigth now the parsing starts on the ViewDidLoad event.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, take that NSMutableArray as a global for that **controller file**.

Be sure u are getting value in NSMutableArray in the controller which holds table view.

simply reload table.

Regards,
Shyam

Comment: It's an instance variable, not a global. But yeah that's the idea.